# Why is $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C} $ a left module?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I was looking at this question:
[$\Bbb{C} \otimes_{\Bbb{R}} \Bbb{C}$ and $\Bbb{C} \otimes_{\Bbb{C}} \Bbb{C}$ are not isomorphic as $\Bbb{R}$-vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579456/bbbc-otimes-bbbr-bbbc-and-bbbc-otimes-bbbc-bbbc-are)
and the author says "Clearly, $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C} $ and $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} $ are left modules". But it is not so clear to me why these are left modules. Can someone please help?

Comment: Any ring is also a module

Comment: Yes, that's true. Every ring is a module over itself. But, how does that make these tensor products left modules?

Comment: $\Bbb C$ is a (left) module. The tensor product of two left modules is a left module.

Comment: Note that a module over a commutative ring can equivalently be called a left or right module

Comment: Can I say that $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C} $ is an $\mathbb{R}$ module as well? Is it because $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$

Comment: Yes, because $\Bbb R$ is a submodule of $\Bbb C$. More formally, you can treat this as a [restriction of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings#Restriction_of_scalars).

Comment: ok thanks. For $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} $, is it an $\mathbb{R}$-module because $\mathbb{C}$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-module? I am sorry for so many questions. I am a first timer at tensor products

Comment: Yes. In general, $A \otimes _{\Bbb F} B$ only makes sense if both $A,B$ are $\Bbb F$-modules